# Anonymous auth by firebase

Tags: java, android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app need to have the simplest type of auth. I dont want to ask from user any FB or google accounts, cell phone number even email address. User just need to register with login and password.

I have found anonymous auth by firebase. But there is a key which can expired.

I need user just register with log+pass and after that stay loged in while the app installed.

Comment: That sounds like you want the user to sign in with password authentication. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth. With any sign-in method, the user's login session to Firebase Authentication will not auto-expire. But their token that grants them access to Firebase will be refreshed every hour. There is no action needed from your app users for this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this type need email. I am looking for only login + pass. Login must be unique

Comment: @BorisRuzanov it does require email but you can always generate a UID as local part and use a custom dummy domain for every user having that UID. This way it will be simple but still it will function as the above suggested way